# Javascript nested for loop displaying data from JSON objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am taking data from a JSON file and using javascript so I can display it on a web page. The json file contains data on a movie cast. Each movie cast has a name, id and characters they play (some play more than one character).

```
"abridged_cast":[
                            {"name":"Tom Hanks","id":"162655641","characters":["Woody"]},
                            {"name":"Tim Allen","id":"162655909","characters":["Buzz Lightyear"]},
                            {"name":"Joan Cusack","id":"162655020","characters":["Jessie the Cowgirl"]},
                            {"name":"Ned Beatty","id":"162672460","characters":["Lots-o'-Huggin' Bear","Lotso"]},
                            {"name":"Don Rickles","id":"341817905","characters":["Mr. Potato Head"]}
                            ],
```

I want to display the cast on the web page as follows:
Starring: Tom Hanks as Woody, Tim Allen as Buzz Lightyear, Joan Cusack as Jessie the Cowgirl, Ned Beatty as Lots-o'-Huggin' Bear & Lotso, Don Rickles as Mr. Potato Head.

What I am getting:
Starring: Tom Hanks as & Woody, Tim Allen as & Buzz Lightyear, Joan Cusack as & Jessie the Cowgirl, Ned Beatty as Lots-o'-Huggin' Bear, & Lotso, Don Rickles as & Mr. Potato Head,

I only want an "&" if the actor plays more than one character and between the last and second last characters. Forr example:
Starring: John as Tiger, Lion, Tree & Crow.

I have spent ages trying to figure if out and I really cannot see what I am doing wrong. Here is my javascript:

```
$(document.body).append('<strong>Starring:</strong> ');
       for (var i = 0;i < movie.abridged_cast.length; i++){
            $(document.body).append(movie.abridged_cast[i].name + " as ");
            for (var j = 0; j < movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length; j++){
                    if(movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j] == movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length -1]
                    // if the character = the character in the last position
                        && movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j].length -1 > 0){
                        // and the position of the character is greater than 0
                        $(document.body).append('& ' + movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j] + ', ');
                    }
                    else {
                         $(document.body).append(movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j] + ', ');
                    }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for characters length and use indexes instead of comparing data

```
for (var j = 0; j < movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length; j++){
                // if more than 1 character
                if(movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length>1
                // and it is the last character in array
                   && j == movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length-1){
                    $(document.body).append('& ' + movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j] + ', ');
                }
                else {
                     $(document.body).append(movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j] + ', ');
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (var i = 0;i < movie.abridged_cast.length; i++){
       if ( movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length > 0 ) {
            $(document.body).append(movie.abridged_cast[i].name + " as ");
            $(document.body).append(movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[0]);
            if ( movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length > 1 ) {
                for (var j = 1; j < movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length-1; j++){
                     $(document.body).append(', ' + movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[j]);
                }
                $(document.body).append(' & ' + movie.abridged_cast[i].characters[movie.abridged_cast[i].characters.length-1]);
            }
            $(document.body).append('<br>');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used arrays to concatenate the strings as I find them easier to work with. In the example in the fiddle I added an extra name to test for when there are more than two names in the character list.

```
var summary = ['Starring '];
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var txt = [], name = data[i].name, chars = data[i].characters;
    txt.push(name + ' as ');
    if (chars.length > 2) {
      txt.push(chars.slice(0, chars.length - 1).join(', '));
      txt.push(' & ' + chars.pop());
    } else {
      txt.push(chars.join(', '));
    }
    txt = txt.join('');
    if (i < data.length - 1) {
      summary.push(txt + ', ');
    } else {
      summary.push(txt + '.');
    }
}

console.log(summary.join(''));
```

Or in your case:

```
$(document.body).append(summary.join(''));
```

**Output**

Starring Tom Hanks as Woody, Tim Allen as Buzz Lightyear, Joan Cusack as Jessie the Cowgirl, **Ned Beatty as Lots-o'-Huggin' Bear, Lotso & Boo-Boo**, Don Rickles as Mr. Potato Head.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5wck/16/)